# Odin FAIL! LZ4 is invalid

Tags: compression, samsung-mobile, lzw, lossless-compression, lz4

I have a ROM that I can flash on Samsung S10 5G(Qualcomm) successfully. My goal is to check whether I can modify `system.img` file of the ROM or not but before modification, I just want to verify that the AP file can be flashed after unpacking and packing of the `system.img`. To check this I have tried following:

**Unpack-Pack AP file:**

A) `tar` flashing:

1. Extracted AP file using `tar -xf AP...tar.md5` command.
2. Compress the extracted files using `tar -cvf AP...tar *`
3. Flash it with Odin3 v3.13.

B) `tar.md5` flashing:
- Get tar by following steps in A) and then run `md5sum -t AP...tar >> AP...tar` and `mv AP...tar AP...tar.md5`

Both `Ap...tar` and `AP...tar.md5` flashed successfully.

**Unpack-Pack `system.img.ext4.lz4`**

1. Extracted AP file using `tar -xf AP...tar.md5` command. Extracted files are "*boot.img.lz4*, *meta-data*, *userdata.img.ext4.lz4*, *carrier.img.ext4.lz4*, *persist.img.ext4.lz4*, *vbmeta.img.lz4*, *dqmdbg.img.ext4.lz4*, *recovery.img.lz4*, *vendor.img.ext4.lz4*, *dtbo.img.lz4*, *system.img.ext4.lz4*".
2. Extract system file using `unlz4 system.img.ext4.lz4` command. This is giving me a `system.img.ext4` Android sparse image.
3. Tried following commands to compress `system.img.ext4` without doing any modification:

```
    lz4 system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4                     - Default Compression
    lz4 -9 system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4              - High Compression 
    lz4 -l system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4              - Default Compression in Legacy format
    lz4 -l -9 system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4           - High Compression in Legacy format
    lz4 -0 -l system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4           - No Compression in Legacy format
    lz4 -B4 system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4             - Default Compression with Block size 4
    lz4 -B5 system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4             - Default Compression with Block size 5
    lz4 -B6 system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4             - Default Compression with Block size 6
    lz4 --no-frame-crc system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4   - Default Compression with no crc frame
```

and make an AP file by replacing the original `system.img.ext4.lz4` file with the compressed file from above command(one at one time) and tried to flash it but every time it fails with **"Odin FAIL! LZ4 is invalid"**

**LZ4 command detail:**
1. Working on Ubuntu 18
2. Using "LZ4 command line interface 64-bits r128, by Yann Collet (Apr 3 2018)"

Tried with "**LZ4 command line interface 64-bits v1.9.2, by Yann Collet**" but get the same result.

**`file system.img.ext4.lz4` output:**

- Original file: `system.img.ext4.lz4: LZ4 compressed data (v1.4+)`.
- My version with both LZ4 (r128 and v1.9.2):

  1. For file compressed with **legacy flag**(-l): `system.img.ext4.lz4: LZ4 compressed data (v0.1-v0.9)`
  2. For file compressed **without legacy flag**(-l): `system.img.ext4.lz4: LZ4 compressed data (v1.4+)`

So, I think it means the file should be compressed without legacy flag.

**Size**

1. With `-9` flag i.e. **High Compression** the output file is of **3.3 GB**.
2. Without `-9` flag i.e. **Default Compression** the output file is of **3.6 GB**.

The **Original file** is of size **3.6 GB** so, I think high compression should not be used.

But still the same error throws by Odin.

Any suggestion why it is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use This:

```
lz4 -B6 --content-size in.img out.img.lz4
```

For More Info: https://www.mankier.com/1/lz4

Found this solution from: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s9/help/how-to-compress-samsung-images-lz4-t3844760

Comment: While this might be the solution, it would be helpful if you could expand a bit more on what this command is doing exactly and why it's the correct one to use.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s9/help/how-to-compress-samsung-images-lz4-t3844760

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I think, Odin wants the original size in the header of `lz4` file(which is the job of `--content-size` flag) and the block size should be 1MB(`-B6`).

Comment: Also worked on Linux Odin4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `system.img.ext4` isn't modified,

```
lz4 -l -9 system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4
```

is supposed to work.
It's strange that it doesn't, although I notice in your example that you are compressing `system.img`, not `system.img.ext4`, so it's unclear if it's the same file.

Suggestion 1 : there might be a checksum somewhere that disallow playing with the lz4 payload. That part is system specific, so it can be difficult to know. You'll have to look around.

Suggestion 2 : compare your original `system.img.ext4.lz4` with the one produced by recompressing with `lz4`. Try to figure out the differences (especially, smaller, larger ?)

Suggestion 3 : use a more recent version of `lz4`. `r128` is actually [very old](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/releases/tag/r128). You could locally compile a more recent version such as `v1.9.2`, which contains ultra modes, able to compress more that -9 (the compression level can be upgraded to -12).

Comment: Corrected the commands in description, last time I have used `unlz4 system.img.ext4.lz4 system.img` so `system.img` was in description. Just now I have used `unlz4 system.img.ext4.lz4` and tried `lz4 -l -9 system.img.ext4 system.img.ext4.lz4` but I get the same result. New thing, I have noticed is the output of file command on the original `system.img.ext4.lz4` is `system.img.ext4.lz4: LZ4 compressed data (v1.4+)` and the another `system.img.ext4.lz4` is `system.img.ext4.lz4: LZ4 compressed data (v0.1-v0.9)`.

Comment: Compile ` LZ4 command line interface 64-bits v1.9.2, by Yann Collet ` from the source code and run `./lz4 -l -9 system.img.ext4 ../system.img.ext4.lz4` command. The output is of **3.3 GB** `system.img.ext4.lz4` file and the `file ../system.img.ext4.lz4` output is `../system.img.ext4.lz4: LZ4 compressed data (v0.1-v0.9)`. The original `system.img.ext4.lz4` is of **3.6 GB**. Any idea how can we make `LZ4 compressed data (v1.4+)` file?

Comment: Tried with `./lz4 -l system.img.ext4 ../system.img.ext4.lz4` command and the output file is of **3.6 GB** but it also has same `file` command output.

Comment: It's unclear if this is a compression format issue. Maybe there is something going on on the Odin side, or even from the Galaxy S10 side, which may prevent editing the payload. Maybe there is a watermark, with a checksum, somewhere, as part of the payload. 
I would recommend looking into Odin documentation regarding loading a different (non-official) payload.

Comment: I get success in flashing simple `system.img.ext4` file by making a `tar` of it but the same thing doesn't work with lz4. Here is the detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58541074/how-to-unpack-modify-pack-and-flash-system-img-ext4-file-using-odin