# How to unpack, modify, pack and flash `system.img.ext4` file using Odin?

Tags: linux, root, android-source, samsung-mobile, flashing

I have a `system.img.ext4.lz4` file that is compatible with my Samsung S10 5G(Qualcomm) device. I have extracted `system.img.ext4` file from the `system.img.ext4.lz4` using `unlz4 system.img.ext4.lz4` command.

I want to play with its content. So I have decided it in two steps:

1. **Flash `system.img.ext4` without modification**:

   - Using `tar -cvf AP.tar system.img.ext4` command, I have created a AP.tar file.
   - Flashed `AP.tar` file using Odin3 v3.13.
   - It flashed successfully.
2. **Flash `system.img.ext4` with modification**:

a) **Modifying**

- With `simg2img system.img.ext4 system.img`, you will get a raw image file named `system.img`
- With `mkdir system`, create directory to mount system.img
- With `sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system.img system/` you will get all files of `system.img` in `system` folder
- With `ls -l system/init.rc` note permissions: 750
- With `sudo chmod 777 system/init.rc` give write permissions
- With `sudo echo "#MODIFICATION " >> system/init.rc` done some modification in `init.rc`
- With `sudo chmod 750 init.rc` reset `init.rc` to the noted permissions

b) **Calculate system sector size**

- With `tune2fs -l system.img | grep "Block size\|Block count"` you will get block size and count
- With `echo $((1553064 * 4096))` multiply both results. I got 6361350144

c) **Packing**

- With `sudo make_ext4fs -s -l 6361350144 -a system system_new.img sys/` you will get `system_new.img` “Android Sparse Image” that has all changes
- With `sudo umount system` unmount the system directory
- With `rm -fr system` delete the system directory

d) **Tar Compression**

- With `rm system.img.ext4` remove original system.img.ext4, Don’t worry you should have a backup of it in lz4 file
- With `mv system_new.img system.img.ext4` rename system_new.img to system.img.ext4 for flashing with Odin3 v3.13
- With `tar -cvf AP.tar system.img.ext4` you will get AP.tar that you can flash with Odin3 v3.13.
- It failed to flash with **FAIL! (Auth)** error.

Please suggest how can I resolve this issue? 
I will be very thankful to you for any little to big suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot resolve this error. It's simple why. It's a modified .IMG file. Since you have a Qualcomm Snapdragon, you are not allowed to flash custom/modified software onto your phone. Reason being is because it's bootloader is locked. There is no way for you to unlock it. The reason the one called AP.IMG worked, is because it wasn't modified at all.